# Counter in smarty

Tags: javascript, smarty

I would like to assign values to a variable depending on a counter's value inside a FOR EACH loop.
So if counter=1, then I assign the value 'a', but if the counter is not 1, then I assign the value 'b'.

This is how far I have gotten but my code is breaking once I add the conditions and the counter change...

```
[{foreach from=$orderArticles item="currOrderArticle"}]
    [{if $counter == 1}]
        products_info.push(["transaction_id='a'"]);
        [{assign var="counter" value=2}]
    [{else}]
        products_info.push(["transaction_id='b'"]);
    [{/if}]
[{/foreach}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smarty already has a iteration counter for foreach loops

```
[{foreach $orderArticles as $currOrderArticle}]
  [{if $currOrderArticle@iteration == 1}]
   ... do something ...
  [{else}]
  ... do something else ...
  [{/if}]
[{/foreach}]
```

Read more about it in the [Smarty documentation for foreach](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.iteration)